# Angular-Mocks module randomly undefined

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, mocha.js, karma-mocha, angular-mock

I have the following coffeescript...

```
beforeEach ()->
  module 'example';
```

About 2/3 of the time (or never if I break there) I get

> ReferenceError: module is not defined

This only thing I can think of is ...

```
beforeEach (done)->
  setTimeout ->
    module 'example'
    done()
  , 50
```

Is there a reason this is happening? I did a search for `module =` in my project and all instances are in an IIFE.

**Update**

I tried upgrading dependencies and I still get this. Also sometimes I get the following...

```
Chrome 53.0.2785 (Mac OS X 10.12.0) LoginModule Default Values FAILED
        TypeError: Cannot read property '$new' of null
            at Context.<anonymous> (src/test/mocha/admin/ldap/LdapModule.test.js:54:24)
Chrome 53.0.2785 (Mac OS X 10.12.0)  "after each" hook for "Default Values" FAILED
        TypeError: Cannot read property '$injector' of null
            at Function.module.$$cleanup (node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2897:31)
            at Context.module.$$afterEach (node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2892:14)
Chrome 53.0.2785 (Mac OS X 10.12.0): Executed 2 of 1 (2 FAILED) ERROR (1.391 secs / 0 secs)
```

Comment: Is this running in a build system?  Or are you manually running it?

Comment: @nix I am running this manually...